# Vaadin ComboBox Multiselect for managing tags

Tags: combobox, vaadin, tagging, vaadin22

Is there a Vaadin component or add-on that provides a ComboBox with multiselect, that works like most tagging systems work? (see picture) Pretty much like Stackoverflow's tagging.
It would be perfect if you could also add new tags this way.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked this one https://vaadin.com/directory/component/multiselect-combo-box

Comment: @TatuLund this is the correct answer so you might as well put it up as an actual answer :-)

Comment: @TatuLund yes, I did some time ago. There was no working version for Vaadin 21. I see that now there is an updated version for Vaadin 22. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 2):

I made such a component for Vaadin 22.0.5, in Typescript. If you need a Flow component you may add a small Java wrapper around it.

[image]

Content of *token-field.ts*

```
import "@vaadin/combo-box";
import "@vaadin/icons";
import "@vaadin/custom-field";
import {customElement, state, property, query} from "lit/decorators";
import {Layout} from "Frontend/views/view";
import {css, html, PropertyValues} from "lit";
import {repeat} from "lit/directives/repeat";
import {ComboBox} from "@vaadin/combo-box";
import styles from "./token-field.css";
import {registerStyles} from "@vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin/register-styles";

@customElement('token-field')
export class TokenField extends Layout {
    private readonly focusEntered = (e: FocusEvent) => {
        const tokenSelection = this.shadowRoot?.querySelector('vaadin-combo-box') as ComboBox<string> | null | undefined;
        tokenSelection?.focus();
    }

    @property({type: Boolean, reflect: true}) required: boolean = false;
    @property({type: Boolean, reflect: true}) invalid: boolean = false;
    @property({type: Boolean, reflect: true}) unique: boolean = false;
    @property({type: String, reflect: true}) label: string = '';
    @property({type: String, reflect: true, attribute: 'helper-text'}) helperText: string = '';
    @property({type: String, reflect: true, attribute: 'error-message'}) errorMessage: string = '';
    @property({type: Array}) knownTokens: Array<string> = ["IT Sicherheit", "Sicherheit", "Umwelt"];
    @property({type: Array}) tokens: Array<string> = ["IT Sicherheit"];
    @state() private filteredTokens: Array<string> = [];
    @query('vaadin-combo-box') private tokenSelectionComboBox!: ComboBox<string>;

    static get styles() {
        return [styles];
    }

    protected render(): unknown {
        return html`
            <vaadin-custom-field label=${this.label} helper-text=${this.helperText} error-message="${this.errorMessage}" ?required=${this.required} ?invalid=${this.invalid}>
                <div class="input">
                    ${repeat(this.tokens, (token, index) => html`
                        <span class="badge" theme="badge pill">
                            <span>${token}</span>
                            <vaadin-button theme="contrast tertiary-inline" title="Remove token: ${token}" @click="${() => this.tokenRemoveClicked(index)}">
                                <vaadin-icon icon="vaadin:close-small"></vaadin-icon>
                            </vaadin-button>
                        </span>
                    `)}
                    <vaadin-combo-box .items="${this.filteredTokens}" allow-custom-value @change=${this.tokenSelectionChanged} @custom-value-set=${this.tokenSelectionCustomValueSet} theme="small transparent"></vaadin-combo-box>
                </div>
            </vaadin-custom-field>
        `;
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        this.addEventListener('focus', this.focusEntered);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        super.disconnectedCallback();
        this.removeEventListener('focus', this.focusEntered);
    }

    protected firstUpdated(_changedProperties: PropertyValues): void {
        super.firstUpdated(_changedProperties);
        this.updateFilteredTokens();
    }

    private tokenRemoveClicked(index: number): void {
        this.tokens.splice(index, 1);
        this.requestUpdate('tokens');
        this.updateFilteredTokens();
    }

    private tokenSelectionChanged(event: Event): void {
        const tokenSelection = event.currentTarget as ComboBox<string>;
        const newToken = tokenSelection.value.trim();

        if (this.unique) {
            const index = this.tokens.indexOf(newToken);

            if (index >= 0) {
                this.tokens.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }

        this.tokens.push(newToken);
        this.updateFilteredTokens();

        tokenSelection.value = '';
    }

    private tokenSelectionCustomValueSet(event: CustomEvent<string>): void {
        const newToken = event.detail.trim();

        if (this.knownTokens.indexOf(newToken) < 0) {
            this.knownTokens.push(newToken);
        }
    }

    private updateFilteredTokens(): void {
        this.filteredTokens = this.knownTokens.filter(token => this.tokens.indexOf(token) < 0);
    }
}

registerStyles(
    'vaadin-combo-box',
    css`
        :host([theme~='transparent']) [part='input-field'] {
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        :host([theme~='transparent'][focus-ring]) [part='input-field'] {
            box-shadow: initial;
        }
        

        :host(:hover[theme~='transparent']:not([readonly]):not([focused])) [part='input-field']::after {
            opacity: 0;
        }
  `,
    { moduleId: 'token-custom-field-styles' }
);
```

*Content of token-field.css*

```
.input {
    min-height: var(--lumo-text-field-size, var(--lumo-size-m));
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: var(--lumo-border-radius-m);
    background-color: var(--lumo-contrast-10pct);
    padding: 0 0 0 3px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 0 var(--lumo-space-xs);
    position: relative;
}

.input::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-radius: inherit;
    pointer-events: none;
    background-color: var(--lumo-contrast-50pct);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform 0.15s, opacity 0.2s;
    transform-origin: 100% 0;
}

.badge {
    margin-top: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.badge vaadin-button {
    margin-inline-start: var(--lumo-space-xs);
}

vaadin-custom-field {
    width: inherit;
}

vaadin-custom-field[focus-ring] .input {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px var(--lumo-primary-color-50pct);
}

vaadin-custom-field[invalid] .input {
    background-color: var(--lumo-error-color-10pct);
}

vaadin-custom-field[invalid] .input::after {
    background-color: var(--lumo-error-color-50pct);
}

vaadin-custom-field[invalid][focus-ring] .input {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px var(--lumo-error-color-50pct);
}

vaadin-custom-field:hover:not([readonly]):not([focused]) .input::after {
    opacity: 0.1;
}

vaadin-combo-box {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```